# Starting a thread from within a tkinter widget

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, tkinter

First, I have to say that I am not an expert at Python. Most of the code I gleaned from examples.

I have done a fair bit of research and haven't been able to find a code configuration that is like what I am trying to do: start a thread from within a custom widget class. I understand that tkinter has issues with multiple threads trying to communicate with a single widget but I don't see that as the case here.

The reason I'm trying to do this is so that each widget can be started/stopped and updated on it's own. This way I can view data from multiple sources from within the same root window and each source can be added/removed at will. I understand that I could code this differently (all in a single class) but I wanted to try it this way. I thought it would make things cleaner.

My thought process on this is as follows:

1. Create a reusable custom widget class.
2. Be able to add multiple widgets to the root window (and also be able to remove them)
3. Each widget will get data and update itself independent from the others.
4. Use threading so that each widget will do what it needs to do in the background. That way all widgets will update at the same time.

My code example shows the basics of what I am trying to accomplish. In the finished program, each widget will have a text box defining where to get it's data.

This test code works fine using Python3 in WindowsXP. Each widget can be added and removed, and will update itself independently from the others.

When I run this same code using Python3 in Fedora20, it crashes when the start button is pressed. The exception is the following:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3.3/threading.py", line 637, in _bootstrap_inner
  self.run()
File "/usr/lib/python3.3/threading.py", line 594, in run
  self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
File "dummy.py", line 44, in updlabel
  self.label.config(text=number)
File "/usr/lib/python3.3/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1263, in configure
  return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)
File "/usr/lib/python3.3/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1254, in _configure
  self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: None
```

So ultimately, I have 2 questions:

1. Why doesn't it work in linux while it does in WindowsXP?
2. Is my approach a valid one and if so, where is my problem in this code?

Code Example:

```py
from threading import Thread
import tkinter as tk
import numpy as np
import time

class Widget(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)

        self.running = False
        self.abort = True

        labelfont = ('times', 20, 'bold')

        self.label = tk.Label(self, text="---", font=labelfont)
        self.startb = tk.Button(self, text="START", command=lambda: self.sbpressed())
        self.remove = tk.Button(self, text="-", command=lambda: self.rbpressed())

        self.startb.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.label.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.remove.grid(row=0, column=2)

    def rbpressed(self):
        self.abort = True
        while self.running:
            self.update()
        self.destroy()

    def sbpressed(self):
        if self.running:
            self.abort = True
            self.update()
        else:
            self.startb["text"] = "ABORT"
            self.running = True
            self.abort = False
            self.update()
            self.t = Thread(target=self.updlabel, args=())
            self.t.start()

    def updlabel(self):
        while self.abort == False:
            number = str(np.random.random_integers(100))
            self.label.config(text=number)
            time.sleep(1)
        self.startb["text"] = "START"
        self.running = False
        self.abort = False

class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()
        self.addb = tk.Button(self, text="+", command=lambda: self.addwidget())
        self.addb.pack()
        Widget(self).pack()

    def addwidget(self):
        Widget(self).pack()

root = tk.Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Works fine for me with Arch Linux, Python 3.4.2

Comment: What do you mean by "I can view data from multiple sources"? What are these sources?  Your example shows calls to random which you definitely don't need threads for. Are you polling other devices or ports?

Comment: By other sources I mean data from the internet. The example code is at it's simplest and just to illustrate the exception I am getting with Fedora20.

Comment: After a bit more research I thought I would add some additional information for future reference. The Version of Python3 I'm running in WindowsXP is 3.4.2 and the version in Fedora 20 is 3.3. I found a question here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17540180/compile-thread-safe-tcl-for-python-on-windows) that had a snippet of code to check to see if the version of Tcl is thread-safe. XP returns '1' and Fedora returns "no such element in array". So, I'm assuming that if Fedora was running Python3.4.2, as matsjoyce did, it would probably work.

Comment: Over the weekend, I installed Fedora 21 on the same computer that had Fedora 20. The code did not work on Fedora 20 (Python 3.3) but did work on Fedora 21 (Python 3.4.1). And the code snippet (above) returned '1' for Python 3.4.1. This doesn't help with the code design question but it may give another data point for someone in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Your basic design is flawed in my opinion. As you mention, tkinter isn't designed to work in multiple threads. You should never call a tkinter function in a thread other than the one that created the root window. That is almost certainly the root of your problem. It *may* work, or it may not -- that is the nature of non-thread-safety.

Also, as a general rule you shouldn't ever call `update` -- it does more than you realize, and is usually completely unnecessary.

The generally accepted solution is that your threads need to put information onto a queue, and your main thread can pull data off the queue and act upon it. For example, you could put a tuple composed of a widget and the string that should be displayed. Your main program can then poll the queue, pulling items off and configuring the widgets with the new text.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I don't disagree with what your saying at all. Just for information's sake though, if I don't call `update` in `rbpressed` the abort signal will never get processed and the code hangs (stuck in the `rbpressed` loop I'm thinking). But since this design is flawed anyway, the point is moot.